# Incredible latency with hosting provider

Tags: magento-1.9

Our customer care team cannot use `admin panel of Magento` **efficiently**. Throughout the day, it happens randomly there will be periods of time where it takes up to 60 seconds to make an entry for a customer. Then they go to the next part of the process and another 60 seconds. This seems rather slow and time consuming.

Is there a way to speed up how magento processes things like this or is it possible server related?

I have though about setting up a local installation of magento on each of the employees desktops and then having them all point to a local server where we would hold the database. All sales would also have to go through this database too, meaning our online hosted sites with other servers would have to point to this one.

I am not trying to start a task like this unless I've check every other way to speed this up.

Yes I've opened a ticket with nexcess our hosting provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do check these before proceeding further:

- All caches should be enable
- Magento must in `PRODUCTION` mode.

If possible, Upgrade your magento to latest version ie 2.1.x because latest version is fast.

I am well aware about `nexcess` and they provide fast hosting site as well as there support team is awesome.

Things will help you:

- No need to install magento on each desktop because it works fast on hosted.
- Try to use cache and speed fast extension if that makes difference.